# Listings with keywords that contain both letters and numbers

Tags: listings, highlighting

I have a listing which needs to highlight keywords with both letters and numbers. Following the advice in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180613/lstlisting-and-keywords-with-special-charakters-or-numbers) I've used the `otherkeywords` to define the keywords which contain numbers. This works for keywords which contain only letters (e.g. `FOO`) and keywords which contain only numbers (e.g. `1234`) but not those that contain both (e.g. `1234FOO`).

Here is an example document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}

\definecolor{Black}{gray}{0.0}
\definecolor{Blue}{rgb}{0.12,0.29,0.53}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\color{Black}\ttfamily, %
  keywordstyle=[1]\color{Blue}\ttfamily\bfseries, %
}

\lstdefinelanguage{mylang}{ %
  keywords={FOO,BAR,BAZ,ARG}, %
  otherkeywords={1234,XYZ1234,XYZ1234HelloWorld}, %
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=none,breaklines=true,caption={},language=mylang]
FOO
BAR
BAZ
ARG
1234
XYZ1234
XYZ1234HelloWorld
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The resulting PDF looks like this:

[image: PDF generated from the LaTeX above]

In this example the keywords `XYZ1234` and `XYZ1234HelloWorld` should be highlighted, but the first three letters (`XYZ`) are not styled consistently with the rest of the keyword. How can I change the language definition to make the highlighting consistent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest thing to do here is to declare all digits as "letters" and define all your keywords with the `keywords` key alone, eschewing the `otherkeywords` key completely:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}

\definecolor{Black}{gray}{0.0}
\definecolor{Blue}{rgb}{0.12,0.29,0.53}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\color{Black}\ttfamily, %
  keywordstyle=[1]\color{Blue}\ttfamily\bfseries, %
}

\lstdefinelanguage{mylang}{ %
  alsoletter=0123456789,
  keywords={FOO,BAR,BAZ,ARG,1234,XYZ1234,XYZ1234HelloWorld}, %
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=none,breaklines=true,caption={},language=mylang]
FOO
BAR
BAZ
ARG
1234
XYZ1234
XYZ1234HelloWorld
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +! Thanks! This also works with `morekeywords`.